# Can't get uploading in zf2 working. File is always not valid?

Tags: file, validation, upload, frameworks, zend-framework2

Im am trying to create a controller that uploads a file for me but I always get the same result. The file isn't valid so he doesn't upload.

The function in my controller is:

```
$upload = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Transfer();
    $upload->setDestination('./data/images/uploads/');

    $rtn = array('success' => null);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $files = $upload->getFileInfo();
        foreach ($files as $file => $info) {
            if (!$upload->isUploaded($file)) {
                print "<h3>Not Uploaded</h3>";
                \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($file);   
                continue;
            }
            if (!$upload->isValid($file)) {
                print "<h4>Not Valid</h4>";
                \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($file);
                continue;
            }
        }

        $rtn['success'] = $upload->receive();
    }

    return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel($rtn);
```

The result is:

```
 <h4>Not Valid</h4><pre>string(8) &quot;files_0_&quot;
 </pre>{"success":false}
```

When I look at $files (print_r()) I get:

```
Array
(
[files_0_] => Array
    (
        [name] => logo_welcome.gif
        [type] => image/gif
        [tmp_name] => /private/var/tmp/phpiufvIc
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 62935
        [options] => Array
            (
                [ignoreNoFile] => 
                [useByteString] => 1
                [magicFile] => 
                [detectInfos] => 1
            )

        [validated] => 
        [received] => 
        [filtered] => 
        [validators] => Array
            (
                [0] => Zend\Validator\File\Upload
            )

        [destination] => ./data/images/uploads
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [ZF2 docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html), file uploading with `Zend\File\Transfer` has been deprecated in favor of using the standard ZF2 `Zend\Form` and `Zend\InputFilter` features.

Having said that, you should use `Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload` to move the uploaded file. You just need to attach the `Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload` filter to your `InputFilter` specification, like that:

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'file',
    'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\FileInput',
    'filters' => [
        [
            'name' => 'FileRenameUpload',
            'options' => [
                'target'               => realpath('./data/uploads/'),
                'randomize'            => true,
                'use_upload_extension' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

And in your controller action:

```
if ($this->request->isPost()) {
    $post = array_merge_recursive(
        $this->request->getPost()->toArray(),
        $this->request->getFiles()->toArray()
    );

    $form->setData($post);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // File uploaded and moved to data/uploads folder
    }
}
```

Take a look in [official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html) for a complete example.